# Can't set public Text = public string[]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'
Hi I'm new to all this. I'm trying to make a monologue system for NPCs. I can't figure out how to make public Text = public string[] sentences. It comes up with an error.

```
public class NPCDialogue : MonoBehaviour

[TextArea(3, 10)]
public string[] sentences;                              //THIS

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Sprite")
    {
        guiObject.SetActive(true);
        playerInRange = true;
        if (guiObject.activeInHierarchy == true && Input.GetButtonDown("Use"))
        {

            if (dialogBox.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                dialogBox.SetActive(false);                  
            }
            else
            {
                dialogBox.SetActive(true);
                dialogText.text = sentences;                    //THIS
```

CS0029  C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'

on "dialogText.text = sentences;" , "sentences" is underlines red and shows the error message above.

there was no red underline when I had just "public string sentences" instead of "public string[] sentences"

extra info: I put a text UI on the public text dialogText in Unity. I have [] with public string[] because i want there to be multiple lines of sentences.

idk

Comment: _string[]_ is a string array _string_ is a single string. _Text_ is a property that accepts only a single string. So you need to transform your string array to a single string. Search for the method _string.Join_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error because the text property needs a string and you are providing a string array. Even though the textbox is multiline you can't just pass in an array. What you need to do is this:

```
//Looping to get every item in the array
for(int i = 0; i < sequences.Length; i++) {
   dialogText.AppendText(sequences[i]); // This is how we add multi-line text. We append text so the next time we perform the action the text is going to be on a new line.
}
```

This should fix it.

Comment: Might want to include a new line separator, but that's optional.

Comment: I don't think so, the append text function already does that. That's why its called append. That's what I know. But yeah If I'm wrong then you're right ;)

Comment: Never used it, so could be either of us. I can't find it in the documentation either.

Comment: Yeah same thing here.

Comment: The documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext?view=netframework-4.8, but it doesn't imply who is right. So guess somebody will have to test it.

Comment: That's a Windows.Forms.TextBox object, which is not neccessarily (and almost certainly not) an ancestor of the text field that Unity is using, as Unity has its own UI systems.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot this was in Unity. Whatever, it's okay. It works for @D3NSHI, so it's a good solution.